# Neo4j server using Java Bolt neo4j-ogm on Weblogic

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I have a problem connecting to a neo4j server from Java EE.

I use :
- **neo4j 3.0.1** in server mode on localhost
- **Weblogic 12.1.3**
- **JEE 7**
- **neo4j-ogm-core 2.0.3**
- **neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver 2.0.3**

My Maven dependencies :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

My ogm.properties in resources/META-INF :

```
#Driver, required
driver=org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.driver.BoltDriver

#URI of the Neo4j database, required. If no port is specified, the default port 7687 is used. Otherwise, a port can be specified with bolt://neo4j:password@localhost:1234
URI=bolt://neo4j:xxxxxx@localhost

#Connection pool size (the maximum number of sessions per URL), optional, defaults to 50
connection.pool.size=150

#Encryption level (TLS), optional, defaults to REQUIRED. Valid values are NONE,REQUIRED
encryption.level=NONE

#Trust strategy, optional, not used if not specified. Valid values are TRUST_ON_FIRST_USE,TRUST_SIGNED_CERTIFICATES
trust.strategy=TRUST_ON_FIRST_USE
```

I use a EJB Singleton to define Session Factory :

```
@Singleton
public class Neo4jSessionFactory {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        sessionFactory = new SessionFactory("com.toto.poc.ejb.data.access");
    }

    /**
     * Get neo4j session
     * @return the session
     */
    public Session getNeo4jSession() {
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }
}
```

it is in "com.toto.poc.ejb.data.access" package.

I have a EJB to define the business method in want to call :

```
@Stateless
public class TopologyBusiness {

    private @EJB Neo4jSessionFactory neo4jSessionFactory;

    public Iterable<Map<String, Object>> getApplication(String irt) {
        String query = "MATCH (a:Application) WHERE a.irt = '" + irt + "' RETURN a";

        Session session = neo4jSessionFactory.getNeo4jSession();

        return session.query(query, Collections.emptyMap());
    }
}
```

But when my client call TopologyBusiness, the init (PostConstruct) method of Neo4jSessionFactory is called, and an error occur :

```
com.oracle.pitchfork.interfaces.LifecycleCallbackException: Failure to invoke public void com.toto.poc.ejb.data.access.Neo4jSessionFactory.init() on bean class class com.toto.poc.ejb.data.access.Neo4jSessionFactory_wi88u8_Impl with args: null
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.Jsr250Metadata.invokeLifecycleMethod(Jsr250Metadata.java:379)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.Jsr250Metadata.invokeLifecycleMethods(Jsr250Metadata.java:352)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.InterceptionMetadata.invokeLifecycleMethods(InterceptionMetadata.java:399)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.injection.EjbComponentCreatorImpl.invokePostConstruct(EjbComponentCreatorImpl.java:55)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.SingletonSessionManager.constructAndInitBean(SingletonSessionManager.java:330)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.Jsr250Metadata.invokeLifecycleMethod(Jsr250Metadata.java:377)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.neo4j.ogm.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: Resource: zip:C:/oracle/wls/12.1.3/user_projects/domains/CMDB/servers/LocalServer/tmp/_WL_user/poc-cdb-ear_ear/a8qjfi/poc-cdb-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/toto.poc/ejb/data/access
    at org.neo4j.ogm.ClassUtils.getUniqueClasspathElements(ClassUtils.java:178)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.scanner.ClassPathScanner.getUniqueClasspathElements(ClassPathScanner.java:158)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.scanner.ClassPathScanner.scan(ClassPathScanner.java:130)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.DomainInfo.load(DomainInfo.java:316)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.DomainInfo.<init>(DomainInfo.java:67)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.neo4j.ogm.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: Resource: zip:C:/oracle/wls/12.1.3/user_projects/domains/CMDB/servers/LocalServer/tmp/_WL_user/poc-cdb-ear_ear/a8qjfi/poc-cdb-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/toto.poc/ejb/data/access
    at org.neo4j.ogm.service.ResourceService.resolve(ResourceService.java:53)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.ClassUtils.getUniqueClasspathElements(ClassUtils.java:175)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.scanner.ClassPathScanner.getUniqueClasspathElements(ClassPathScanner.java:158)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.scanner.ClassPathScanner.scan(ClassPathScanner.java:130)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.DomainInfo.load(DomainInfo.java:316)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

The root cause seems to be :

```
Caused By: org.neo4j.ogm.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: Resource: zip:C:/oracle/wls/12.1.3/user_projects/domains/CMDB/servers/LocalServer/tmp/_WL_user/poc-cdb-ear_ear/a8qjfi/poc-cdb-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/toto.poc/ejb/data/access
```

I have no idea why it wants to look into a zip in the classpath ...
Thank for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can finally resolve my problem, I browsed odd forums and found someone who had similar issue on JBoss.
So I managed to transpose this solution to Weblogic.

First, you need to create your own **resource resolver** to provide the way to deal with "zip".
Overwrite ResourceResolver and implements resolve method like below :

```
public class Neo4jResourceResolver implements ResourceResolver {

    @Override
    public File resolve(URL resource) throws Exception {

        switch (resource.getProtocol()) {
            case "file":
                return new File(resource.toURI());
            case "jar":
            case "zip":
                String jarPath = resource.getPath().substring(0, resource.getPath().indexOf("!"));
                return new File(jarPath);
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then create a file named "**org.neo4j.ogm.classloader.ResourceResolver**" in path "**src/main/resources/META-INF/services**".
This file contains only one line, the path to your custom ResourceResolver class :

```
com.toto.poc.core.access.ucmdb.Neo4jResourceResolver
```

And it's magic, it works !!!

Neo4j will now explore the jar archive, found your NodeEntities and map it to your graph :)